# Every element of $H \times1$ commutes with every element of $1\times K$ and $H \times 1 \cap1 \times K = (1_H, 1_K)$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

> Let $H$ and $  K$ be groups and let $H \times 1 = \{ (h, 1_K) | h \in H\}$ and $1 \times K = \{(1_H, k) | k \in K\}$, where
> $1_H$ and $1_K$ denote the identity elements of $H$ and $K$ respectively.
>
> Prove that,
>
> (i) Every element of $H \times1$ commutes with every element of $1\times K$ and $H \times 1 \cap1 \times K = (1_H, 1_K)$.

Attempt,

take any $(h,1_K) \in H \times 1$ and $(1_K,k) \in 1 \times K$,
then $$(h,1_K).(1_H,k)=(h1_H,1_Kk)=(h,k)$$

$$(1_H,k).(h,1_K)=(1_Hh,k1_K)=(h,k)=(h,1_K).(1_H,k)$$
$
\therefore$ Every element of $H \times1$ commutes with every element of $1\times K$

For the second part,

- It clear that  $(1_H,1_K) \in H \times 1$ and $(1_H,1_K) \in 1 \times K$ this follows $(1_H,1_K) \in H \times 1 \cap 1 \times K$
- Suppose $ a \in H \times 1 \cap 1 \times K$ and $a \not= (1_H,1_K)$,
- This follows $a \in H \times 1$ and $ a \in 1 \times K$ hence by definition of $H \times 1$ and $ 1 \times K$ ,

  $a=(h_1,1_K)$ and $b=(1_H,k_1)$ where $h_1 \in H$ and $k_1 \in K$.

  this follows $(h_1,1_K)=(1_H,k_1) $ so $h_1=1_H$ and $k_1=1_K$

which contradicts $a \not= (1_H,1_K)$,That is  $H \times 1 \cap1 \times K=(1_H, 1_K)$

Can anyone verify my answer? Second part is not sure.

Comment: It looks fine to me. Your grammar needs work though.

Comment: It all seems correct! For the last deduction, I recommend not phrasing it as a proof by contradiction: you want to prove that $ a \in H \times 1 \cap 1 \times K$ implies $a = (1_H,1_K)$, and your argument does just that—you start by assuming that $ a \in H \times 1 \cap 1 \times K$ and directly show that $a = (1_H,1_K)$.

Comment: @Shaun Can you explain why you said "grammar needs work though"?

Comment: @GregMartin Got it. Thank you very  much.

Comment: Well, for instance, your use of "this follows" is peculiar. You use capital letters after commas.

Comment: @Shaun Got it. thank you very much.